# How to toggle Between Two Windows in Linux Mint Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.2

Currently to Toggle between two windows I have to use `Show the window selection screen` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd>) > <kbd>Right</kbd> > <kbd>Enter</kbd>`.

Or alternate between `Cycle through open windows` and `Cycle backwards through open windows`.

Is there any single key which I can use to toggle between two windows?

What is the keybinding to toggle between two windows?

Comment: Doesn't ALT + Tab work?

Comment: It's been years since I used cinnamon, but back then I believe it behaved like most (non-tlling) window managers, and gave you windows in a MRU (most recently used) order when switching with alt+tab, so if you have two windows you use a lot more than the others on your desktop that will generally be what you need.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I just noticed that if I use `ALT + Tab`, it toggle windows. However, if I press `ALT + Tab`, then only release `Tab` than it acts differently. However, it will do the trick. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between the two most recently used windows. Holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> and releasing <kbd>Tab</kbd> presents a list of available windows, which can then be scrolled through by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. This works in the majority of non-tiling desktop environments including Windows and MacOS.